# Visual Studio 2019 for Mac can not build Xamarin Forms project

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

New to mac programming, but I've not found anything, not a single thing about the problem I have and I really need your help.

I've created a Xamarin Forms project on my PC (Windows 10, latest VS + latest VS tooling) and I've been developing an app there for both iOS and Anroid. I've been testing it on Anroid and everything works.

Now when I'm trying to build the iOS project on my mac with latest VS and Mono i get the following error:

`/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Current/Microsoft.Common.props(3,3): Error MSB4019: The imported project "/Users/michael/Desktop/Dev/Suborghttps:/github.com/meJevin/PVWeather/LRadio/LRadio/LRadio/obj/LRadio.csproj.*.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. (MSB4019) (LRadio)`

I have no idea what it means and can't find anything in the internet. Help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: clean your bin and obj folders, restart VS, try again.  If that doesn't work, open your csproj file in a text editor and look for any refs to a "props" file.  Googling "xamarin msb4019" turns up lots of interesting hits for me, have you tried that?

Comment: As I said, nothing is related to my specific error of file `Microsoft.Common.props(3,3)` when googling about `xamarin msb4019`. Tried your suggestions, of course. Nothing.

Comment: @lilbroomstick Hi , maybe the environment of ios has something wrong with it.You can have a try with creating new project to check whether build successfully first.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting my iPhone and my Mac a couple of times, as well as cleaning all the caches and stuff the problem seems to be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have now solved it, I suspect the cause was the `:` in the folder name in the path (`Suborghttps:`), as this seems to confuse the Microsoft compiler, perhaps due to the meaning of colon on Microsoft operating system file systems.